# I'm confused by this code

Tags: python, django, unicode

This following is from the django source code ([`Django-1.41/django/utils/encoding.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.1/django/utils/encoding.py#L73));

```
try:
    s = unicode(str(s), encoding, errors)
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    if not isinstance(s, Exception):
        raise

    # If we get to here, the caller has passed in an Exception
    # subclass populated with non-ASCII data without special
    # handling to display as a string. We need to handle this
    # without raising a further exception. We do an
    # approximation to what the Exception's standard str()
    # output should be.
    s = u' '.join([force_unicode(arg, encoding, strings_only,
        errors) for arg in s])
```

My question is:  In which case will `s` be an instance of Exception?
 when s is an instance of Exception, and s have neither str or repr attribute. Than this situation happen. Is this right?

Comment: Can I write `raise "a_string"` in Python?

Comment: The sole argument to raise indicates the exception to be raised. This must be either an exception instance or an exception class (a class that derives from Exception).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s` will be an exception if someone called the [force_unicode](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.1/django/utils/encoding.py#L54) function with a subclass of  Exception and the message includes unicode characters.

```
s = Exception("\xd0\x91".decode("utf-8"))
# this will now throw a UnicodeEncodeError
unicode(str(s), 'utf-8', 'strict')
```

If the code in the `try` block fails then nothing will be assigned to `s`, so s will remain what the function was initially called with.

Since `Exception` inherits from `object`, and `object` has had the `__unicode__` method since Python 2.5, it might be the case that this code existed for Python 2.4 and is now obsolete.

UPDATE:
After opening a pull request, this code has now been removed from the Django source: https://github.com/django/django/commit/ce1eb320e59b577a600eb84d7f423a1897be3576

Comment: Thanks , I think when s is an instance of Exception, and s have neither __str__ or __repr__ attribute. Than this situation happen. Is is right.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
>>> force_unicode('Hello there')
u'Hello there'
>>> force_unicode(TypeError('No way')) # In this case
u'No way'
```

Comment: But in  s = unicode(str(s), encoding, errors).  str(s) will return a string. so s will be u'No way' after this statement.